# Array of Range Address

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to enter a series of cell addresses into an array in VBA.

My code currently states:

```
Do
    Range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to add to the Array. Press ""Cancel"" when all Ranges have been added.", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    If Range1 <> False Then
        ReDim Preserve TestArray(Count)
        Set TestArray(Count) = Range1.Address
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop Until Range1 = False
```

At the end, I am looking for something like (A1, C3, D6, G8)

This doesn't work.

I would then use these ranges later by saying something like:

TestArray(i).Value = TestArray(i).Value * 1.01

How can I create an array of ranges?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I select the input box as Type 0, I can recieve a string such that cell A1 will be stored in the array as a string like "=R1C1"

I could then parse this and use the Cells function

But someone might know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of creating and using an array of cell *(Range)* addresses:

```
Sub RangeArray()
    Dim addy()
    addy = Array("A1", "B9", "C11", "D17")
    For i = 0 To 3
        Range(addy(i)).Value = i + 100
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
Sub test()
    Dim TestArray() As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim el

    Do
        Set Range1 = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set Range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to add to the Array." & _
                            "Press ""Cancel"" when all Ranges have been added.", _
                            Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'if Cancel pressed - exit do
        If Range1 Is Nothing Then Exit Do

        ReDim Preserve TestArray(count)

        TestArray(count) = Range1.Address
        count = count + 1
    Loop While True
    'test loop through array
    For Each el In TestArray
        MsgBox "Address " & el & ", Value " & Range(el).Value
    Next el
End Sub
```

But personally I prefer using [`Collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yb7y698k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) rather that `ReDim Preserve`:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim TestCol As Collection
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim el

    Set TestCol = New Collection

    Do
        Set Range1 = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set Range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to add to the Array." & _
                            "Press ""Cancel"" when all Ranges have been added.", _
                            Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'if Cancel pressed - exit do
        If Range1 Is Nothing Then Exit Do

        TestCol.Add Item:=Range1.Address
    Loop While True
    'test loop through collection
    For Each el In TestCol
        MsgBox "Address " & el & ", Value " & Range(el).Value
    Next el
End Sub
```